# Замена текста на иконки (js, react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне от сервера приходят ссылки на социальные сети. Как правильно заменить текст ссылки (item.label) на иконки ?

Код:

```
const social = items.data.social.map((item, index) => {
    return <a key={index} href={item.link}>{item.label}</a>
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```js
const social = items.data.social.map((item, index) => {
  return <a key={index} href={item.link}><i>{item.label}</i></a>
})
```